# getElementsByClassName into automatic ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code as a header menu to define data to be fetched with ajax into a different div when the user clicks into one of the buttons.

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-devided" data-toggle="buttons">

    <label class="btn btn-transparent grey-salsa btn-circle btn-sm active">

    <input type="radio" name="options" class="toggle" id="option1">Day</label>

    <label class="btn btn-transparent grey-salsa btn-circle btn-sm">

    <input type="radio" name="options" class="toggle" id="option2">Week</label>

    <label class="btn btn-transparent grey-salsa btn-circle btn-sm">

    <input type="radio" name="options" class="toggle" id="option3">Mont</label>

</div>
```

I also plan on using **setInterval** to automatically refresh data every few minutes. My question is: how to identify the currently selected option using the **label class active** as an identifier? How would **getElementsByClassName** be used for this situation?

I was considering getting the innerHtml and then using an if condition in the ajax processing.

Thanks!

Comment: You could loop through the `label` elements by calling `getElementsByTagName` and then checking if the `className` contains `active`. If it contains `active`, you call `nextElementSibling`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using `querySelector` for this:

```js
var active = document.querySelector('label.active input');

if (active) {
    console.log(active.id);
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-group btn-group-devided" data-toggle="buttons">

    <label class="btn btn-transparent grey-salsa btn-circle btn-sm active">

    <input type="radio" name="options" class="toggle" id="option1">Day</label>

    <label class="btn btn-transparent grey-salsa btn-circle btn-sm">

    <input type="radio" name="options" class="toggle" id="option2">Week</label>

    <label class="btn btn-transparent grey-salsa btn-circle btn-sm">

    <input type="radio" name="options" class="toggle" id="option3">Mont</label>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and the child selector:

```
var checkedButton = document.querySelector('label.active > input');
```

However, the more robust solution (since it doesn't depend on "meta data" from CSS classes) might be to iterate over the radio buttons and see which one is selected:

```
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('input[name=options]');
var checkedButton;
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    if (buttons[i].checked) {
        checkedButton = buttons[i];
        break;
    }
}
```